# How can I adopt the memory allocated by a PyArray / numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

## Objective

I'd like to take ownership in c++ of the numpy ndarray memory buffer returned from a python function called by my c++ extension ( when this make sense ... contiguous, `Py_REFCNT(array)==1`).

## Background

My hope is to pass off this pointer to another library (which I cannot change). I can construct a `Buffer` for this library from a raw pointer, which it adopts. This library uses copy-on-write buffers, so I cannot simply hold on to a copy of the ndarray object until the `Buffer` object is gone.

## What I've tried

No luck with clearing the `NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA` flag.
Nor with setting `array->data = 0` and `array->nd=0`.
I still get "double free or corruption" errors.  I surmise this is because the ndarray is still somehow freeing that memory.

## Environment

I am restricted to python 2.6 and numpy 1.4.1 (RedHat/CentOS 6)

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You should probably just keep the whole array around until you're done with its memory if you want to use its memory as your own.

Comment: Depending on what Python function you're calling, you may have the option of providing it with an output array to use, with memory you own.

Comment: edited ... I cannot just keep the array around until the last reference is done because I don't control that aspect.  Also, this should work with a generic user callable object that returns an ndarray.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance but your statement that the library adopts AND does copy-on-write has made me curious. Could you - only if you have the time - briefly explain what the rationale of copy-on-write is if you own the object? Thanks, and good luck with your question / project.

Comment: Think of it as notionally similar to a `std::move` from one library (numpy) to another.